# Conditionally Load Styles and Scripts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a solution to conditionally load scripts and styles on specific Wordpress pages. I've searched for solutions, but have hit a dead end. I haven't been able to use php selectors, such as is_page(), in the functions.php file to do this. Here is an example of my past attempt:

```
function blog_style() {

    if ( is_page('blog') ) { 

        wp_enqueue_style( 'blog' );

    }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'blog_style' );
```

I have a feeling this is because the functions.php file is loaded before the page has been identified. Any advice is helpful. I have a basic understanding of php and Wordpress codex. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I understand your confusion in this matter and must confess that WordPress sometimes has strange ways to handle things.

First of all; you should enqueue scripts and styles in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_styles');

function themeslug_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style(...);
}
```

Or in shorthand-/anonymous-function-format, if you prefer:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_style(...);
});
```

The basic idea of your `is_page('blog')` in an if-statement is correct. But also check out this [detailed info about conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) - maybe there are better ways to target the blog-page of your website (see "The Blog Page" on the linked resource).

You must use the if-statement inside your function, because it is only at the point of `wp_enqueue_scripts`, where the function is run, that WordPress has information about the actual content ready.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    if (is_home()) {
        wp_enqueue_style('themeslug-stylename', URL-to-your-style);
        wp_enqueue_script('themeslug-scriptname', URL-to-your-script);
    }
});
```

**Addition:** You are right, the `functions.php` file is mainly used to set everything up and connect functions as actions to WordPress hooks. Therefore, the code is executed quite early in the WordPress execution flow to give you access to as many hooks as possible. The downside is, as you experienced, that many things are not directly accessable at this point.

Comment: So in this example it applies to the blog page, which would be is_home(), but my ultimate goal is to use this on any page that I want. where should this go? I tried inputting this in my page.php file, but nothing happened. Here's the code I used... `<?php add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
        if (is_page( 'Home' )) {
            wp_enqueue_style('random', '/random.css');
        }
    }); ?>`

Comment: You should put this code inside of your functions.php file. What obviously makes loading the stylesheet fail in your example is the path you are using to enqueue the stylesheet. If the stylesheet is residing inside your theme directory, you must prepend `/random.css` with `get_template_directory_uri() .` - it becomes `get_template_directory_uri() . '/random.css'`. WordPress unfortunately does not give you any error if there is no stylesheet found on the location you specified. You logic, anyhow, is correct.

Comment: That was the missing piece. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong hook here. Try

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blog_style' );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function. I had used this function to dynamically load scripts on different post types and pages. I used the `screen_id` to specify the current page.

Comment: Isn't this meant for admin pages?